# Simple wrapper to use IEnumerable as a producer in a producer-consumer pattern

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, producer-consumer

I have a relatively simple problem: I have an `IEnumerable<T>`, which takes considerable time to yield each term. This is then used by another piece of code, which takes considerable (but not identical) time to process each term.

As I understand it, this is a classic producer-consumer scenario, so I'm choosing to use a `BlockingCollection<T>` so that I can produce and consume concurrently.

To support this, I have a simple wrapper:

```
class EnumerableProducer<T>
{
    public readonly BlockingCollection<T> ProducerCollection;

    public EnumerableProducer(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        ProducerCollection = new BlockingCollection<T>();
        AddItemsToBlockingCollection(ProducerCollection, source).Start();
    }

    private static Task AddItemsToBlockingCollection(BlockingCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return new Task(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                collection.Add(item);
            }
            collection.CompleteAdding();
        });
    }
}
```

Any code having an `IEnumerable<T>` and wanting to use it as a producer passes it to the constructor, then accesses it through the `ProducerCollection`.

Interested in a general review, but in particular:

- Is this the simplest/most idiomatic way to do achieve the overall goal?
- Any comments/suggestions on naming.
- Extensibility (e.g. adding cancellation or parallelizing the enumeration of the source) probably fall under YAGNI for me at the moment, but if there are alternative designs which would make this kind of extension in general easier to implement, I would be interested.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx), as it's designed to do precisely what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DanLyons Thanks! Ideally I don't want to add any new dependencies to the project for what's at the moment a very simple requirement, but I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: I feel that more context/code would be helpful for giving a review. Is the `IEnumerable` CPU- or I/O-bound? Can you give an example of an `IEnumerable` that you would use with this, and maybe also code for a consumer? Is this meant to be a general solution for any slow `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think the implementation is too leaky - it should not expose how the blocking internals are achieved since if if decide do change this you might have to change a whole lot of application code which violates the open-closed-principle (the O part of SOLID). This can be easily fixed by making the class `IEnumerable<T>` and using [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `BlockingCollection`.
2. I think the more idiomatic way to start a new task is to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`.
3. I would rename it into `BlockingEnumerable` since that what it is.
4. Since you're talking about long running operations you may want to add a method of canceling the task.
5. It might be useful to add a capacity for the intermediate blocking collection as well to provide better control of how much data is cached.

Slightly refactored code:

```
class BlockingEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> _ProducerCollection;

    public BlockingEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        _ProducerCollection = new BlockingCollection<T>();
        AddItemsToBlockingCollection(source);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _ProducerCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private void AddItemsToBlockingCollection(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                _ProducerCollection.Add(item);
            }
            _ProducerCollection.CompleteAdding();
        });
    }
}
```